# laravel retrieve json and save into database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting cinema title + times using API from Cinelist, I then want to save these values into a database.

At the moment, it does save but only 1 record, the last one. However, I want it to save each one.

Also each time it is run I want to update existing records instead of creating new ones unless there are more results.

So usually there are 5 records, each time I run the function I want to update the database with the new 5 records, however, if it's a different day and there are 6 records I want to update 5 records and insert 1 extra one so there is 6.

My code so far:

```
function odeon(){
        $data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565');
        $data = json_decode($data);

        foreach($data->listings as $listing){
            $title = $listing->title;
            $time = implode(', ', $listing->times);
            $id = + 1;

            $films = Film::where('id', $id)->first();
            if (!$films) {
                $films = new Film();
            }

            $films->title = $title;
            $films->times = $time;
            $films->save();
        }
}
```

Comment: Your id is reset for every new film object you create because it is in your foreach scope. So the id will be `1` every time and you will keep updating this object.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use eloquent's updateOrCreate method to insert non-existent data and update existing data.

```
function odeon(){
    $data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565');
    $data = json_decode($data);

    foreach($data->listings as $listing){
        $title = $listing->title;
        $time = implode(', ', $listing->times);

       Films::updateOrCreate([
                             'title' => $title,
                             '$times' => $time
                             ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get:  MassAssignmentException
title

Comment: In your model, you have would have to add protected $fillable = ['title','times'];

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment

Please see the details of mass assignment here

Comment: That works great, that is for 1 cinema but what if I want to add another cinema? I don't want a conflict between id

Comment: You will have to add a column to identify to which cinema the film belongs to. In this case, even if the Titles and time are same, the entries will have different cinema_ids and it will avoid the conflicts.

Comment: There is a field with business_id which is a foreign key  so if 1 cinema has business_id = 1 and another one has 2 how would I tell the function to overwrite id that match business_id? Keep in mind that business id is saved at the same time as title and times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146549/discussion-between-plbit-and-przemek).